# Indesign All Layer to illustrator

Tags: adobe-indesign, adobe-illustrator

Hi Guys is it possible to move layers of indesign to Illustrator.

For Example If we have multiple layers in indesign  all layers should moved or exported to Illustrator.

How can it be done, Do any one have script for this?

Any IDEA.??

Answer (score 0):

Not possible by default but you may think of exporting document to PDF switching layers on/off and later add those files as placedObjects within Illustrator. You can think of a one single script if you use the BridgeTalk object.

Comment: Hello Loic Thanks for the review.
But when we export the interactive PDF from indesign  and try  place in illustrator the whole  PDF will exported to single layer not has layer in PDF.

If i try to write a script how to link layer of illustrator to Indesign. I think its a high end scripting i am not so equipped to write it.

So could you please guide me.

Comment: Hi the key point here is to generate as many pdfs as layers from InDesign. But as you can export a layer to PDF you need to play with layers visibility on/off and export the document itself. As PDF may host several pages, you may restrain the page range to page 1.
Once taht done, you have as many PDF files as indesign layers count. Then you can place thos PDF one by one in a liiustrator script. All of these are basic actions. see scripting guide for starters.

Comment: Thanks Loic its gr8 option .I will go through it.

One more question can we Move indesign layer (5 Layer) to photoshop with same layer  and get text edited with out moving to illustrator.

I got  a script (LayersToSmartObjects) while googling which loads all the layer of  indesign to photoshop but the text will not get editted.

Any Idea on this???

Comment: Smart objects can be edited through double click. However if you want a native photoshop text layer, that would imply actually create a photoshop text layer and fill the contents from the indesign layer "contents". Problem is that a layer can host many things within InDesign. So that would be a loop for targeting text frames contents only. Good luck with that ;)